# homework, java, Avoiding deadlock when using notify() instead of notifyAll() on multiProducer/singleConsumer model

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep, producer-consumer, notify

so I'm working on this report, and the last assignment is to create a producer/consumer model with `n` Producers and one Consumer, the trick is that i have to make it work with `notify()` instead of `notifyAll()` in the *put* and *get* methods.

I figure just leaving it as is in the *get* method isn't a problem, since there's only the one consumer, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to make sure the `notify()` in the *put* method only calls the consumer thread, instead of waking up another producer and causing deadlock.

Comment: How _I_ would solve that problem is, I would use a `ReentrantLock` instance instead of using Java `synchronized` statements, and I would allocate _two_ condition variables; one for waking the consumer, and one for waking producers.  But, if you _must_ use `Object#wait()` and `Object#notify()` then you'll have to invent some means for a producer thread to know when it returns from a `wait()` call whether the notify was intended for the producers or for the consumer.  If it was intended for the consumer, then the producer thread will have to re-notify, and then go back to waiting.

Answer (score 0):

You can't decide who gets woken up. That's why you need additional logic so if the wrong thread is notified, it will know that it shouldn't run and `notify()` another thread (and re-`wait()` itself).